# React Router rerender component by self-clicking a link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I use `react-router-dom` v6

## The Code

```
<NavLink to="/pathOne" className="ripple">label1</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/pathTwo" className="ripple">label2</NavLink>
```

## The Problem

When you click one link or another, the `Route` component renders just as it should. But what if `"/pathOne"` is active and I click on it again? Nothing happens.

Is there a way to force rerender route element by clicking on active link?

I can refresh all page if I set `reloadDocument` prop but this is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you really want is for the route component to rerender each time the link to its route is clicked then just have those components call the `useLocation` hook. Each time the link is clicked a new `location` object reference is created. The new `location` object reference is enough to trigger the component using it to be rerendered.

Example:

```
const PathOne = () => {
  useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("PathOne rerender");
  });

  return <h1>PathOne</h1>;
};

const PathTwo = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("PathTwo rerender");
  });

  return <h1>PathTwo</h1>;
};
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NavLink to="/pathOne" className="ripple">
        label1
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink to="/pathTwo" className="ripple">
        label2
      </NavLink>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/pathOne" element={<PathOne />} />
        <Route path="/pathTwo" element={<PathTwo />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-rerender-component-by-selfclicking-a-link]